# Cannot complete second part of 'I Could Make You Care'

Tags: pc, fallout-new-vegas

I'm stuck at the second part of the Companion quest ['I Could Make You Care'](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/I_Could_Make_You_Care), for the companion Veronica Santangelo, where you need to find 3 technologies, either:

- Vault 22's farm info
- Guided Rangefinder (aka Euclid's C Finder)
- Pulse Gun from Vault 34

Previous to this quest I had already completed the two quests ['There Stands the Grass'](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/There_Stands_the_Grass), and given the info to Thomas Hildern. I had also already completed the quest ['That Lucky Old Sun'](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/That_Lucky_Old_Sun), and diverted power to Archimedes II (for Euclid C Finder).

So even though it pops up saying I need to find the range finder, and go to Vault 22 to find the info, and sets up waypoints, going to the waypoint doesn't complete any objectives, nor does it update, so even though I have the Euclid's C-Finder in my inventory and can call down orbital strikes, the objective still says "Find information about the rangefinder" and "Go to Vault 22 and search for the info".

So I tried the 3rd option, going to Vault 34 and retrieving the Pulse Gun. I did that, and returned to Elder McNamara, and the objective showed up as completed, saying "Return the technology to Elder McNamara". However, Veronica will not trigger any conversations regarding the technology, as the Wikia says she would, and talking to Elder McNamara grants no quest dialogue.

So now I'm stuck at this point, and have no idea what to do.  How am I supposed to finish this part of the quest? I have tried several of the fixes they said, such as putting the Pulse Gun in Veronica's inventory, and taking it out again, but that doesn't do anything.

Comment: Are you playing on the PC? If so, there should be a solution involving console commands.

Comment: Have you tried this? "Note: Switching is always possible by going back to the comm station and re-downloading the information as this will prompt a dialogue with Veronica enabling you to choose a different path." to switch to the third path?

And are any other quests active with the elder?

Comment: Have you tried all the fixes on this page? http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/I_Could_Make_You_Care#Fixes

Comment: @Ids That's the first place I checked, and none of those fixes work.

Comment: @memescientist Did you ever resolve this? I've come across the same issue.

Comment: For anyone who comes across this, the thing that solved it for me was making sure I choose the pulse gun as an option and never switch it. Originally I chose the Vault 22 option and switched when I realized it wouldn't work because I had already done the Hildern quest.

Comment: @AHungerArtist I had to resort to a previous save and followed your trick and it worked! If you could put it as an answer I wouldn't mind accepting it, thanks!

Comment: @howdareyou Done. Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing that solved it for me was making sure I choose the pulse gun as an option and never switch it. Originally I chose the Vault 22 option and switched when I realized it wouldn't work because I had already done the Hildern quest.